# how to tell if a page has valid content using python without opening the page

Tags: python, fetch

I am working on this python script to check Facebook pages. it is looking something like this

```
    url = 'https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=3063889{}'.format(i)
   
    urlHandler = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    html = urlHandler.read()
    print(html)
```

is there any way to tell if a page has content or not without opening the link?
like between [this](https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=101953928330429) and [this](https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=101953928330421)

and this is using BeautifulSoup

```
html_text = requests.get(vgm_url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    print(link.get('src'))
```

Comment: Have you tried parsing the html content using bs4 BeatifulSoup and find image element that has source image is the guy with the wrench? I tried several pages and it seems that that image has static URL. You can extract the URL via inspect tool in browser and match whether that URL exists in html content to identify invalid page.

Comment: yes I tried without success. I will append what I did to the original post maybe you can tell what I did wrong